# IE8 displaying page incorrectly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

For one reason or the other IE8 is not displaying my webpage properly. It works on every other major browser but everything is helter-skelter when I try to open the page on IE8 and since majority of the users of this page primarily use IE8, I cannot ignore it. Here's the link to it: http://www.gradschool.purdue.edu/gradexpo/mailinglist/

Comment: Can you describe more on "helter-skelter".  I do not have IE-8

Comment: It doesn't appear to work well in IE9 either. Back to the drawing board on your layout I feel. You might want to ask on the Webmasters site on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set a doctype. Put this at the very top of your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

IE put itself into 'quirks' or Compatibility mode when it doesn't see a doctype, which will mess up your layout. Specifying a doctype will kick it into Standards mode which will remedy most problems. IE is still pretty useless at rendering CSS properly, so you might still have some issues.

Note you could also use the HTML 4.01 Strict doctype, but this will give the same result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

get a doctype at the top of your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

then run it through http://validator.w3.org

and fix other errors

Comment: You also have a lot of <META> tags in your <body>, these need to be shifted inside the <head> tag for a start.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the critical error of a missing `doctype` as others have pointed out, you have a few serious HTML errors.

[W3C Validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.gradschool.purdue.edu/gradexpo/mailinglist/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

You have repeated your closing tags for `</body>` and `</html>`.  You also have a couple unused closing `div` tags, `</div>`.  All of the `meta` tags in your `<body>` need to be moved to within the `<head>` section.   Browsers will handle these kinds of errors with unpredictable rendering.